# Can't login into mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication

I've just downloaded MySql using [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265685/how-to-reinstall-mysql) after installing it before.
I've thought that it would solve my problems but, whenever I try to login into MySql via the terminal I'm prompted to enter the password though I've already logged in with the following command:

```
mysql -u user -p password
```

Here is what happening:

```
$> mysql -u user -p MYPASSWORD
Enter password:
```

And after I insert my password again...

```
$> mysql -u user -p MYPASSWORD
Enter password:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'MYPASSWORD'
```

I'd like to know if there's a solution to this weird problem.

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword
```

So in your case:

```
mysql -u user -p123456
```

By adding a space between `-p` and your password, you're actually setting the database to use, which is why you get the error `unknown database`.

The other solution would be:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

In that case, your password will be asked by the terminal. It is a bit more secure as your password does not stay in plain text in your terminal history. But if your password is 123456, I guess you're not too concerned by security ... ;)

Comment: haha not really, It's just my development computer. Thanks for the great answer (And the laughter :P)

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, I would use:

```
mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
```

you can try it.... ;)